# Replace parts of a string in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column which contains the string in the below format:

```
Account Number [1.######] belongs to customer [2.########] residing in [3.######] for the selected period.
```

I want to replace the placeholders of 1, 2 and 3 with actual value which will come from a table.

Something like below:

```
Account Number 1234 belongs to John residing in London for the selected period.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Ram

Comment: This is a task for anything other than T-SQL, in my opinion. It's string manipulation is poor at best.

Comment: You just need three nested `replace` - one replacing the string `'[1.######]'` with the desired value and so on

Comment: What is your SQL Server version? `SELECT @@VERSION;`

Comment: it’s the latest version as we are using Azure SQL database.

Comment: Replace statement works but I do not want to hardcode the placeholders in the query. Rather it will be useful if the placeholders are replaced dynamically by identifying the square braces.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from SQL Server 2016 onwards, it supports an enhanced version of the `FORMATMESSAGE()` function.

Message can have a maximum of 2,047 characters.

Here is a conceptual example of it.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @message VARCHAR(2048) = 'Account Number %s belongs to customer %s residing in %s for the selected period.';
DECLARE @AccountNo VARCHAR(20) = '1234'
    , @Customer VARCHAR(20) = 'John'
    , @Location VARCHAR(20) = 'London'
    , @Result VARCHAR(2048);

SET @Result = FORMATMESSAGE(@message
            , @AccountNo
            , @Customer
            , @Location);

-- test
SELECT @Result;
```

**Output**

```
Account Number 1234 belongs to customer John residing in London for the selected period.
```

Answer (score -1):

In your select statement add the following:

```
[New Field] = CONCAT('Account ',table.field,' belongs to customer ',table.field,'residing in 'table.field' for theselected period.')
```

Comment: I feel you have very much missed the point here.

Comment: In what way do you feel I have missed the point? The OP was asking for a way to have a column create a string which pulls from other tables, this is what I have provided.

Comment: Where are you **replacing** the place holder? You've taken a literal and removed the bits yourself.